LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmr/m/up' undefined using `OT1/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 8
I have this code and get the warning which is in the title. I am not sure why.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{euler}
\title{tikzcdtest}
\date{}
\author{TSE}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}


The warning is harmless so you can ignore it, but I will raise with the team, we should adjust somewhere so the package and the base fd file agree on whether the default upright shape is n (normal0 or up (upright)

+1 for the clear test file:-)

The warning is harmless so you can ignore it, but I will raise with the team, we should adjust somewhere so the package and the base fd file agree on whether the default upright shape is n (normal) or up (upright).
You can make the warning go by telling LaTeX to do what the warning says it is doing anyway, using n for the up shape:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{euler}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{cmr}{m}{up}
      {<->ssub*cmr/m/n}{}
\title{tikzcdtest}
\date{}
\author{TSE}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}

